# UIActivityViewController and UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

How do I combine a UIActivityViewController and a UIDocumentInteractionController? The Mail app and the Tumblr app seem to compine a UIActivityViewController with a UIDocumentInteractionController because their controllers also show the "Open in" buttons besides the UIActivities. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You should upload the image using inbuilt image service or delete the link as it's broken.

Answer (score 3):

Use `presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` in UIDocumentInteractionController

Comment: This does not work. It does not show any actions typical to UIActivityController such as Message, Email, and Print

Comment: First, thank you so much! I was searching for this almost two hours… fiddling around with UIActivities etc, but it could have been so simple :)

@fishinear: check (and set) the `UTI` type of your documentInteractionViewController. Probably, you may need to set it manually after allocation.

Comment: @tubtub I have set the correct UTI. I think the problem is that Apple does not know the UTI, and therefore does not know what it can do with it. I should maybe set an incorrect UTI that Apple knows about.

Comment: @fishinear Yeah, this should work. You could try `kUTTypeText` or `kUTTypePlainText` and review the results.