# UIActivityViewController or UIDocumentInteractionController with WhatsApp and FB

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, whatsapp, uiactivity

I need to have Facebook and WhatsApp as sharing options for my image. I've already implemented UIActivityViewController, where i can share via Facebook and `UIDocumentInteractionController` where i can share via WhatsApp. I don't know how to merge these things.

**UIActivityViewController:**

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewContoller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] 
       initWithActivityItems:@[@"Test", image] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewContoller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**UIDocumentInteractionController:**

```
NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController 
                 interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
    _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero 
                                    inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

I want to have both of them in one popover, however I have no idea how to achieve it. Any tip please?

I've checked out [StackOverFlow question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591028/uiactivityviewcontroller-and-uidocumentinteractioncontroller), but it doesn't help me at all. My file is .wai (for WhatsApp) so when i try to send it via FB file is unable to open. Also it shows all options, while i want only 2(FB+WhatsApp) to be visible. Following the [StackOverFlow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591871/open-in-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-how-to-filter-options-in-sdk-ios-6) I can show only FB (working one, because i set normal image) but can't add WhatsApp (no .wai file, i don't know what to do with UTI). Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: It would be even better to implement WhatsApp as UIActivity. The problem is that i have no idea how to treat UTI and where to put this savePath part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change type of file:

```
- (void)share {
    NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/tmptmpimg.jpg"];
    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_img, 1.0) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
    [_documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}

- (void)documentInteractionController:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller willBeginSendingToApplication:(NSString *)application {
    if ([self isWhatsApplication:application]) {
        NSString *savePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/tmptmpimg.wai"];
        [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_img, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
        controller.URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath];
        controller.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    }
}

- (BOOL)isWhatsApplication:(NSString *)application {
    if ([application rangeOfString:@"whats"].location == NSNotFound) { // unfortunately, no other way...
         return NO;
    } else {
         return YES;
    }
}
```

This way we can use all options- Facebook, Twitter and custom WhatsApp.

The problem with showing only selected options is still not solved, but it's the minor one.

Comment: what is isWhatsApplication here?

Comment: Isn't this will create an extra file in Home Directory after sharing?

Comment: So whats the UTI for Facebook, Twitter and Instagram?

Answer (score 0):

To exclude non-desired sharing options (the second part of your question), assuming your `UIActivityViewController` object is called `activityController`, set the excludedActivityTypes property, like so:

```
activityController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                 UIActivityTypePrint,
                                                 UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                                 UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
```

Comment: It's a UIDocumentInteractionController not UIActivityViewController.