# Share image through WhatsApp, just show WhatsApp icon

Tags: ios, whatsapp, uidocumentinteraction

I use this piece of code, but it shows other apps.

```
NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"ABC" withExtension:@"png"];
if (URL)
{
   self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];
   [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];
   CGRect rect = self.view.frame;
   [self.documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:rect inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

How can I show the WhatsApp icon only?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the WhatsApp developer docs: https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/iphone/23559013

Here is the relevant bit:

> Alternatively, if you want to show only WhatsApp in the application
>   list (instead of WhatsApp plus any other public/*-conforming apps) you
>   can specify a file of one of aforementioned types saved with the
>   extension that is exclusive to WhatsApp:
>
> images - «.wai» which is of type net.whatsapp.image
>
> videos - «.wam» which is of type net.whatsapp.movie
>
> audio files - «.waa» which is of type net.whatsapp.audio

So in order to share an image you would set the `UTI` of your `UIDocumentInteractionController` to `net.whatsapp.image` and append the extension `.wai` to your filepath.

Additionally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20885042/uiactivityviewcontroller-or-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-with-whatsapp-and-fb) may have some helpful example code.

Comment: The code you posted does not include the part where you save the file in the first place. That is necessary in order to save it with a different name, can you edit your question and include the rest of the code?